# Renaming a crate with a hyphen doesn't compile anymore

Tags: rust

This no longer compiles:

```
extern crate "my-crate" as my_crate1;
```

What's the new syntax? I did not find anything by searching.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dashes in extern crate names can be replaced with underscores. So your example should be

```
extern crate my_crate as my_crate1;
```

Or if you want the underscored name, using the following will work

```
extern crate my_crate;
```